Spring JPA doesn't create table in database
I've downloaded project from spring.start.io, set up application.properties file, created entity class but when I ran project JPA didn't create any table in my database. But as same set up with my old project it worked well. Anyone encountered same problem can please help me?
I also tried change version of spring boot to 3.2.3 as my old project but it didn't work. Beside my spring log didn't appear any error so I don't know how I can search this
This is my application.properties file:
spring.application.name=JPA
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

server.port=8888

My entity class Task.java:
@Entity
@Table(name="task")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    
    private String taskName;
    
}

My pom.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.JPA_Learn</groupId>
    <artifactId>JPA</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JPA</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


My bad, I put Entities package outside package that contain Application file. If someone got the same problem, check where your put your package or file. Took me 2 days after tried to delete, retry and search, stupid mistake, haha.
